# formatting fields to show currency in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to format a field for salary and can't seem to bring out the currency symbol when doing the formatting. I have tried using the text box field formatter and then I have tried using the expression below.

When I re-run my report after entering the expression I get a `#ERROR` in the output. Is there anything else I can try?

```
=Format(Fields!number.Value, "£")
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Set the textbox format as `C0`, i.e. currency to 0 decimal places:

[image]

This will be affected by the report **Language** property - set to `en-GB` for pounds, as in your example:

[image]

You can also set the textbox properties, which also gives you the option to set the symbol outside of the report language:

[image]

Finally, you can use a string like:

```
=Format(Fields!number.Value, "C0")
```

This does change the field type to a string, unlike the other options, which can have en effect if exporting to Excel.

Comment: Thanks for this... If I am coverting it into a string, can't I use the ".ToString" function?

Comment: `.ToString("C")` and `.ToString("C0")` should work (assuming that the localization is set properly as you stated). You can specify a format. But nice answer so +1 :)

Comment: Hi, @Sam. Seems like a fair assumption, but on my sample data `=Fields!number.Value.ToString("C0")` displays `#Error` for me with the runtime error `Input String was not in a correct format` (SSRS 2008). Pretty small test, admittedly.

Comment: the small test I did yesterday was `123.56.ToString("C0")` (which actually surprised me when it worked).

Comment: just checked and `=CDbl(Fields!number.Value).ToString("C0")` works.

Comment: Thanks, @Sam. It seems like it depends on a combination of the data and the expression whether a format can be specified. I've removed an earlier erroneous comment where I stated you can't specify a format - this is true in some circumstances but certainly not in others. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 6):

currency number format

```
  =Format(Sum(Fields!MyField.Value), "C")
```

Answer (score 2):

thanks for your help. I have found another solution to my problem.

I have changed all the formatting properties and then entered the following expression:

`=CDbl(FormatNumber((CDbl(Fields!number.Value)),2))`

Not the most elegent of solutions but it works.