# Change number formatting based on values of another column in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I want to change the format of the values based on another column. 
Basically, based on Type column , I want to change the number format. Any help will be appreciated.

Below is the current tablix report. It has 3 columns (Type, US and UK). it always has 4 rows (Sales, Quantity, Percentage and Notes). 
I tried using Format function but it is throwing me error for other rows.
Switch(Fields!Quantity.Value = "Quantity",FormatNumber(Fields!US.Value,0))

**Type        US       UK**

Sales       123.36   2122.2

Quantity    2345     3451

Percentage  0.81     0.91

Notes       NetSales GrossSales

Date    May 20 2020 11:00AM  May 20 2020 12:00PM

Now, I want to display them as below

**Type        US       UK**

Sales       $123.36  £2,122.2

Quantity    2,345    3,451

Percentage  81%      91%

Notes       NetSales GrossSales

Date      11AM   12PM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your dataset query actually returns those 3 columns as they appear in your sample then you need to be testing the `Type` column....

I recreated the recordset using the following code in the dataset query

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (Type varchar(10), US varchar(50), UK varchar(50))
INSERT INTO @t VALUES
    ('Sales', '123.36','2122.2'),
    ('Quantity', '2345','3451'),
    ('Percentage', '0.81',' 0.91'),
    ('Notes', 'NetSales','GrossSales')
SELECT * FROM @t
```

I then aded two identical tables, one to show the unformatted values and the other to show them after the format expressions have been applied.

[image]

For the `US` Column expression is used the following expression which basically converts each text entry to a value then applies from formatting.

```
=SWITCH(
    Fields!Type.Value = "Sales", FORMAT(VAL(Fields!US.Value),"$0.00"),
    Fields!Type.Value = "Quantity", FORMAT(VAL(Fields!US.Value),"n0"),
    Fields!Type.Value = "Percentage", FORMAT(VAL(Fields!US.Value),"p0"),
    Fields!Type.Value = "Date", FORMAT(cdate(Fields!US.Value), "HH:mm tt")
    True, Fields!US.Value
    )
```

The UK expression is almost identical.

```
=SWITCH(
    Fields!Type.Value = "Sales", FORMAT(VAL(Fields!UK.Value),"£0.00"),
    Fields!Type.Value = "Quantity", FORMAT(VAL(Fields!UK.Value),"n0"),
    Fields!Type.Value = "Percentage", FORMAT(VAL(Fields!UK.Value),"p0"),
    Fields!Type.Value = "Date", FORMAT(cdate(Fields!UK.Value), "HH:mm tt")
    True, Fields!UK.Value
    )
```

**Note** the finale `True` acts like an `ELSE`

The final output looks something like this...

[image]

**For reference.**
"n0" means use thousand separattor with zero decimal places and "p0" means, format as percentage with zero decimal places.

**UPDATE AFTER MORE INFO FROM OP**

If you have a date as a string e.g. `May 20 2020 11:00AM` then you can add an extra line to the switch, before the `True, Fields!UK.Value. I've edited the expressions above to allow for dates are strings

using `Fields!Type.Value = "Date", FORMAT(cdate(Fields!UK.Value), "HH:mm tt")`

all we are doing is converting the string to a date using CDATE() then formatting tat to show the hours only in AM/PM format.

=FORMAT(cdate(Fields!dt.Value), "HH:mm tt")

Comment: One last thing (I hope), if there is date field in another row and need to convert into hour then below works?                                 =SWITCH(
    Fields!Type.Value = "Sales", FORMAT(VAL(Fields!UK.Value),"£0.00"),
    Fields!Type.Value = "Quantity", FORMAT(VAL(Fields!UK.Value),"n0"),
    Fields!Type.Value = "Percentage", FORMAT(VAL(Fields!UK.Value),"p0"),
  Fields!Type.Value = "PDate", FORMAT(VAL(Fields!UK.Value),"hh:mm tt"),
    True, Fields!US.Value
    )

Comment: Two things. 1). Note the typo (corrected in my answer for the last line of the UK column expression).   2). Can you update you question and show an example as I'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: Sorry for not explaining clearly. I meant if there is 5th row called Date. How do we convert it?

**Type        US       UK**

Sales       123.36   2122.2

Quantity    2345     3451

Percentage  0.81     0.91

Notes       NetSales GrossSales

Date    May 20 2020 11:00AM  May 20 2020 12:00PM

Below is what I need

**Type        US       UK**

Sales       $123.36  £2,122.2


Quantity    2,345    3,451

Percentage  81%      91%

Notes       NetSales GrossSales

Date      11AM   12PM

Comment: If depends on what format the date is in. if it's a string then you may have to convert it to a date first then apply the format. Note that typo in the like condition I accidentally put Field!US.Value for the UK expression this should obviously be UK. Edit the question so show the exact date format I can I will edit the answer accordingly. Please don;t add comments to explain, it's better to edit the original question. I'll check in again later tonight if I get chance

Comment: If I use the below statement then Date is displaying accurately i.e. 11AM and 12PM but rest all rows are showing as #Error.                                                 =SWITCH(
    Fields!Type.Value = "Sales", FORMAT(VAL(Fields!UK.Value),"£0.00"),
    Fields!Type.Value = "Quantity", FORMAT(VAL(Fields!UK.Value),"n0"),
    Fields!Type.Value = "Percentage", FORMAT(VAL(Fields!UK.Value),"p0"),
    Fields!Type.Value = "Date", FORMAT(cdate(Fields!UK.Value), "HH:mm tt")
    True, Fields!UK.Value
    )

Answer (score 1):

The "**Switch**" function is really good for your scenario.
The only thing that missing is the output for your conditions,
You can find it here:

[SSRS - formatting fields to show currency symbol with two place decimal](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/ssrs-formatting-fields-to-show-currency-symbol-with-two-place-decimal)

or here

[formatting fields to show currency in SSRS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20469258/formatting-fields-to-show-currency-in-ssrs)